# Scroll Spy en angular 2

Tags: angularjs-2.0, scroll

alguien sabe como implementar un scrollspy en Angular 2?
he buscado algun ejemplo de algun Plunkr o algo pero no he podido encontrar nada para usar.

Answer (score 1):

este lo he usado yo y me ha funcionado.
https://github.com/JonnyBGod/ngx-scrollspy

De todos modos si no te funcionase, recuerda que importándote $ (Jquery) puedes trabajar con librerías Jquery aunque no es lo más óptimo, pero siempre te puede ayudar.
Aquí tienes una librería Jquery para usar ScrollSpy también:
https://github.com/r3plica/Scrollspy

Para usar Jquery en Angular 2,4 y 5 debes hacer lo siguiente.

En tu index.html añadir la librería

En tu component declarar la librería $ para que esté disponible para usar.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var jquery:any;
declare var $ :any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 title = 'angular 4 with jquery';
 toggleTitle(){
 $('.title').slideToggle(); //
}

}
```

Y después en tu vista lo usas normalmente en el html con el evento (click), como lo usarías sin Angular.

Espero que te sirva!